# How to limit log4j messages from a 3rd-party library

Tags: java, log4j

I am using apache's pdfbox in a Java Swing application; it is evidently configured to give many log4j messages while running (no evidence that log4j2 is in use). I would like to limit those messages to, say, WARNING and above so that I can see my own logging messages. I'm sure what it outputs is useful in some context, but not my current one.

```
07:03:51.053 [SwingWorker-pool-2-thread-1] INFO org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer - Your current java version is: 1.8.0_181
07:03:51.058 [SwingWorker-pool-2-thread-1] INFO org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer - To get higher rendering speed on old java 1.8 or 9 versions,
07:03:51.058 [SwingWorker-pool-2-thread-1] INFO org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer -   update to the latest 1.8 or 9 version (>= 1.8.0_191 or >= 9.0.4),
07:03:51.059 [SwingWorker-pool-2-thread-1] INFO org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer -   or
07:03:51.059 [SwingWorker-pool-2-thread-1] INFO org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer -   use the option -Dsun.java2d.cmm=sun.java2d.cmm.kcms.KcmsServiceProvider
07:03:51.059 [SwingWorker-pool-2-thread-1] INFO org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer -   or call System.setProperty("sun.java2d.cmm", "sun.java2d.cmm.kcms.KcmsServiceProvider")
07:03:52.851 [Finalizer] DEBUG org.apache.pdfbox.io.ScratchFileBuffer - ScratchFileBuffer not closed!
07:03:57.514 [Finalizer] DEBUG org.apache.pdfbox.io.ScratchFileBuffer - ScratchFileBuffer not closed!
07:04:01.340 [Finalizer] DEBUG org.apache.pdfbox.io.ScratchFileBuffer - ScratchFileBuffer not closed!
```

I have created the log4j.properties file:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, theConsoleAppender

log4j.appender.theConsoleAppender=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.theConsoleAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.theConsoleAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x --- %m%n

log4j.logger.org.apache.pdfbox.type=warn
```

Hoping that the 'warn' would be used for the pdfbox messages, but that didn't work.

I added the following line to my app startup:

```
Logger.getRootLogger().setLevel(Level.WARN);
```

hoping that it would affect the loggers evidently producing the above messages, but that didn't work.

How can I, either through configuration or program call, limit the log4j messages output by the pdfbox library?

Comment: Why do you have `type` in your log config line? Seems like it should be `log4j.logger.org.apache.pdfbox=warn` (leave out `.type`).

Comment: ok, took out ".type" from that line, but I still get 1300 lines of output, mostly starting with `08:27:58.184 [SwingWorker-pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG org.apache.fontbox.`,  with some starting `08:27:58.898 [SwingWorker-pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG org.apache.pdfbox.`.

Comment: Then configure the logging for `org.apache.fontbox` as well. Note: What you write after `log4j.logger.` usually corresponds to the package name of what's doing the logging. So: `log4j.logger.org.apache.fontbox=warn`.

Comment: You should not use java 1.8.0_181. Use the latest jdk8 from Amazon Corretto. You should also not use log4j, migrate to log4j2.